# python combining two lists of tuples into one big list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I've searched around and it seems like nobody has asked this question (or at least I can't find it).

I have two lists of tuples and I want to join them to one list of tuples.

```
first = [('a', 1), ('b',2)]
second = [('c',3), ('d',4)]
```

I have tried appending, joining, zipping, but none of those are quite right. I want to get this:

```
wanted = [('a', 1), ('b',2), ('c',3), ('d',4)]
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

EDIT: I feel really stupid... of course its the one thing I forgot to try :(

Comment: wanted = first + second

Comment: As you can see, _many, many, many_ people have asked this exact question, with several additional variations.

Comment: reduce(lambda a,b: a.extend(b) or a, [first, second, third])

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `+`

```
>>> first = [('a', 1), ('b',2)]
>>> second = [('c',3), ('d',4)]
>>> first + second
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```

Comment: Alternatively, depending on the use-case, `itertools.chain`